# How can I get a signature line to stay at the bottom of the page?

Tags: microsoft-word

There does not seem to be a SE for MS Office?

I have a Word document with a signature line (name printed underneath). Is there a way to force that paragraph to always be at the bottom of the page? I cannot put it in the footer, that is being used already (unless I can have two footers?)

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/set-text-direction-and-position-in-a-shape-or-text-box-HA010355853.aspx

Comment: Why won't it stay at the bottom after the last paragraph? Are you trying to place it regardless of the amount of text in the body of the document?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already have a footer, that doesn't prevent adding other content to it; you don't need two separate footers to accomplish what you describe.  Just make the existing footer space taller as needed for the additional content and add the signature line above the existing footer contents.  This won't change anything about the existing footer contents.  It will function like a footer above your existing footer.